# "Can't resolve reference" when using Azure Service Bus package in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, linker, servicebus

I'm using the [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) in my Xamarin.iOS project. This works fine for Debug builds, when linking is off, but when I want to make a Release build for distribution (with the default setting Link Framework SDKs only), it fails with the following error:

> /Users/Gerwin/Public/Projects/Sandbox/Test3/MTOUCH: Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions::AcquireTokenAsync(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext,System.String,System.String,Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential)', referenced from the method 'System.Void Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AdalAuthenticationContext/d__0::MoveNext()' in 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.14.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. (MT2101) (Test3)

Configuration:

- macOS 10.15.1
- Visual Studio for Mac 8.3.8 (build 8)
- Xamarin.iOS 13.6.0.12
- .NET Core SDK 3.0.100

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new iOS app via the wizard
- Add the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus (the latest version, 4.1.1)
- Add some code to call the API, e.g. in the `FinishedLaunching` method in `AppDelegate.cs`:

  ```
  InvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
      var client = new TopicClient("", "", RetryPolicy.NoRetry);
      var message = new Message(new byte[0]);
      await client.SendAsync(message);
      await client.CloseAsync();
  });
  ```

(you'll need a `using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;` too)

- Now, a Debug build for the Simulator works fine
- However, a Release build for an iOS device produces the error mentioned above

The [build output](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/8b402f80760bdb57ed84e660ababce0b) shows a slightly different but related error:

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate', referenced from the method 'System.Void Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.ClientCertificateAzureServiceTokenProvider/d__8::MoveNext()' in 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.14.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Adding the NuGet package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory separately doesn't help; disabling linking works, but produces much larger .IPA files. (Which is a problem in my actual app, which uses much more libraries.) I've tried to use the [`--linkskip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#skipping-assemblies) option, e.g. using `--linkskip=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` doesn't help. I ended up using an older version (2.0.0) of the ServiceBus package.

Comment: Also having this issue, downgrading to V2.0.0 of the package solved the problem. Or set your linker options to Don't Link but that makes your IPA size significantly larger.

Comment: Yes, I ended up downgrading the package as well. Sorry for not posting that ...